# How to filter out GIS objects a user doesn't have access rights to?

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to have GeoServer ONLY return items from an SQL Server data source that the current user has access to see.

This is probably better understood with a simple example...

EXAMPLE

Let's assume I have an SQL database containing Geo-referenced "buildings" which have specific access rights assigned to them:

```
Building1 : allowed users: Silvia, Tony
Building2 : allowed users: Silvia
Building3 : allowed users: Mary
```

A layer "BuildingLayer" is created on the "Buildings" table and properly shows all the buildings on a map.

Users and Access Rights are managed in a separate system/database and can change dynamically at any moment, but might be "sync'd" with the GIS database if required (for performance reasons).

QUESTION

How can the "BuildingLayer" view ONLY show "building1" and "building2" for Silvia, "building1" for Tony, and "building3" for Mary?

ADDITIONAL NOTES

Ideally, I would be looking at some kind of "hook" so that when GeoServer "fetches" all the "Buildings", I could actually check who's making the request, test their access rights, and potentially filter out items the user doesn't have access to.

All the existing user / role security of GeoServer is very static, such as for securing access to a whole "layer", but that doesn't work at all in this case, since the access rights and users are all dynamic. Also it would make no sense to create a specific layer per user/table.

What could be the ways to approach this access-rights filtering problem so that nobody can see data they are not entitled to?

Comment: what have you tried so far? have you used `geofence`? if so how? is your connection set up to use the correct users to connect to the database?

Comment: @IanTurton - GeoFence doesn't help, as it allows filtering on users, roles, service type (WMS...), and such, not dynamic filtering on the actual source data (the "buildings" in my example.)
The point is, a "layer" shows all the "buildings" from the source DB table, but I need a way to only have the buildings the user has access to. Out of the box, seems I can only assign rights at the 'layer' level - on/off per user role. I rather want to filter out building that are in the DB, but that the user has no rights to.

Comment: then why tag with `geofence`? I would consider a parameterised view (or a better table design)